# How scroll end page with vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I scroll to the bottom of the page?

```
scroll(){
    let container = this.$el.querySelector('#scrollingChat')
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight
}
```

I'm doing this, and always calling my api answers, but it does not go to the bottom of the page

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
```

This is will instantly scroll to the bottom of any page.

Comment: No problem. I know its not "Vue-ish" but it gets the job done

Comment: If you want it to be smooth you could also use `requestAnimationFrame ` and `window.scrollTo(0, i)` with some recursion magic :) happy coding

Comment: Does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

or you can use smooth scroll: https://github.com/alamcordeiro/vue-smooth-scroll

Answer (score 2):

If you create an anchor in your page like so:

```
<div id="top"></div>
```

you can use:

```
let elmnt = document.getElementById('top');
elmnt.scrollIntoView(false);
```

This page explains what the different alignment parameters do for scrollIntoView:

**true** - scrolls to top of element

**false** - scrolls to bottom of element

default it true

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

Comment: Of course, this example was being used to scroll to the top of a page, but if you put the anchor at the bottom of the page it should work the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) as reference.

Code wise safest use with VueJS is, using `nextTick()` and `ref` attribution, especially if execution is triggered following an event (Example: Button Click). + works best if you use some VueJS framework.

Scroll can be applied with `smooth` behavior for a nicer UX.

**Example for specific div**

```
<template><div ref="myScrollTarget">...</div></template>
<script>
...
methods: {
  scrollToBottom() {
    const targetRef = this.$refs.myScrollTarget;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      targetRef.scrollTo(
        {
          top: targetRef.scrollHeight,
          left: 0,
          behavior: "smooth"
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
...
</script>
```

**Example for full page (window)**

```
<template><div>...</div></template>
<script>
...
methods: {
  scrollToBottom() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      window.scrollTo(
        {
          top: document.body.scrollHeight,
          left: 0,
          behavior: "smooth"
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
...
</script>
```