# How to link to another bottom page?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

This is my code

```
<a :href="page_4_state.data.dealerUrl" class="f-green" target="_blank">
<u>Searching for number</u>
```

Normally, It will link to another page.
But I want to link to the bottom of the another page.

Comment: How does `dealerUrl` look like?

Comment: It's form api
dealerUrl
: 
"https://skl.co.th/contact/branch-10126"

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215955/how-scroll-end-page-with-vue-js

Answer (score 0):

I see your url dealer in the comment use a "href anchor", like this:

```
<a :href="page_4_state.data.dealerUrl+'#footer'" class="f-green" target="_blank">
<u>Searching for number</u>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_anchor